# How can we terminate in a finite amount of time?

Tags: probability, statistics

What's the difference between:

1.Always terminates in a finite amount of time

2.Terminates in a finite amount of time with probability 1

Extension:
Are there any more ways we could add to the list? (I doubt it)
Are there any other similar situations?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are you aware in general of the difference between an event occuring almost surely (i.e., with probabiilty 1) and an event occuring surely/always?

Comment: It is the same difference between "impossible" and "improbable". The former means that the event is empty, and the latter just means it has probability zero.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, No, I am not aware of the difference, it is something I shall investigate more.

Comment: @AsafKaragila does improbable not simply mean 'unlikely' compared to impossible's empty event?

Comment: Improbable has probability $0$, whereas impossible means the empty event. E.g. if you choose a real number in $[0,1]$ is is improbable that this number is $\sqrt2$, or a rational number, or that the number lies in the Cantor set, but it is still possible; whereas it is impossible that you choose $2$, since it lies outside the said interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that for some sets and probability measures on them, there are subsets that have measure $1$ that are *not* the entire set. For example, consider $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the probability measure given by the traditional Lebesgue measure. Now look at the set $(0, 1]$. It clearly is a strict subset of $[0, 1]$, but note that its measure is still $1$. So if we had a program that took inputs in $[0, 1]$, and all of them terminated except for the program run on input $0$, the program would terminate with probability $1$ but would not *always* terminate.

Comment: How could we prove that the measure of (0,1] is still 1?
And to clarify, in order to have a program that does not _always_ terminate, we need some input for which it is impossible to terminate?

Comment: @Somniare To prove that for the Lebesgue measure (from first principles) is a bit involved, as the definition of the Lebesgue measure is not exactly trivial. Informally, the Lebesgue measure finds "the best approximation" of a set as a union of disjoint (closed) intervals, and then adds the length of those intervals. There are a lot of details, but they won't make much sense without some measure theory. So any interval $(a, b]$ (open, closed, or half-open) has length $b - a$ under the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Somnaire And yes, a program always terminates if and only if it terminates for every input. Almost surely might have some mathematical subtlety attached, but always does not :)

Comment: Okay, I hope I will learn more about measure theory at university, thanks for all the help!